# How can i calculate all lottery combinations instead of printing them?(C#)

Tags: c#

Lottery 6/49 Problem:
The below code prints all possible combinations
How can i calculate all combinations instead of printing them?

```
   static void Main()
   {
        for(int i1=1; i1<=44; i1++)
        {
            for(int i2=i1+1;i2<=45;i2++)
            {
                for(int i3=i2+1;i3<=46;i3++)
                {
                    for(int i4=i3+1;i4<=47;i4++)
                    {
                        for(int i5=i4+1;i5<=48;i5++)
                        {
                            for(int i6=i5+1;i6<=49;i6++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(i1+" "+i2+" "+i3+" "+i4 +" "+i5+" "+i6);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

   }
```

Comment: instead of `Console.WriteLine` just write i++; and declare a int type variable at the top of the loop.

Comment: To calculate all combinations, have you googled permeation's and combinations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about basic math

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic combination problem.  `nCk` where `n` is the number of options(49) and `k` is the number of options to pick(6).

The formula is `n!/k!(n-k)!`

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
   nfac = nfac * i;
}

for (int j = 1; j < k; j++)
{
   kfac = kfac * j;
}

for (int p = 1; p < (n-k); p++)
{
   nkfac = nkfac * p;
}

Console.WriteLine(mfac/(kfac*nkfac));
```